# Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/xslt/xDocument'

Tags: c#, xslt, infopath, msxml

I'm attempting to XSLT transform an InfoPath document from XML to HTML, and I get the following error:

```
Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/xslt/xDocument'.
```

Is it even possible to transform the document? I note the XSL makes use of functions such as `xdXDocument:GetDOM` which look like the old MSXML syntax. Can you add support for MSXML during the transform?

For reference the Namespace is:

```
xmlns:xdXDocument="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/xslt/xDocument"
```

[This article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/9f6e9ac7-cb20-41f7-b5ab-2a015c94b1aa) suggests that you simply use the Print View of the InfoPath document - but I think that might be unique to InfoPath 2007 (post-2010 it seems you can print any view).

---

As an aside, I also tried using MSXML and I got a similar error:

```
Namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/xslt/xDocument' does not contain any functions.
```

Here's my MSXML code:

```
var xml = new MSXML2.DOMDocument60();
xml.load(txtXmlFilePath.Text);
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtXslFilePath.Text);

// Seemingly need to strip out first <?xml... /> line to work
string sXsl = string.Join("\n", lines.Skip(1).ToArray());

var xsl = new MSXML2.DOMDocument60();
xsl.loadXML(sXsl);

string html = xml.transformNode(xsl);
```

So the basic question remains - how do you transform an XSLT transform an InfoPath document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xdXDocument:GetDOM()` is an extension function that is used to access data from secondary data sources in InfoPath. I have worked with the task of using InfoPath view XSLTs to convert InfoPath XML documents to HTML, and the only way I know of to handle these extension functions is to write extension objects that implement them (you could implement dummy extension objects that just return empty nodesets for these functions if you don't need them.

The alternative is to create a view that doesn't have any references to the form's secondary data sources.

Comment: Do you have any info on creating extension objects?

Comment: I assume you are using .NET, and if so I think there are a few articles about it on MSDN. Here is one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321702

Comment: Thanks so it appears the key line is `xsltArgList.AddExtensionObject("urn:XYZ", XYZ)`.

Comment: Yes, that's right. One more thing to look out for is that there is also an `xdXDocument:get-DOM()` function that's used to reference the main data source when the current context is a secondary data source. A limitation of C# is that method names can't contain hyphens, so the only workaround I've found is to do a string find-replace on the XSLT to replace `xdXDocument:get-DOM()`.

Comment: Do you know how to get it to handle "<xsl:if test="function-available('xdImage:getImageUrl')">"?

Comment: AFAIK, the XSLT processor should handle `function-available()` automatically. Have you run into issues with it?

Comment: As per that sample, are you using the `XPathDocument` and `XslTransform` classes? I'm trying to generate the HTML images and set the their URLs, but it seems `function-available()` skips over the subsequent calls to `xdImage:getImageUrl`. Any code examples you can share would be very helpful.

Comment: XslTransform is deprecated. You should use XslCompiledTransform. Not sure if that will make a difference, but it's conceivable that it could. I assume you've defined the getImageUrl function in the correct namespace?

Comment: Can you give me an example with using a namespace?

Comment: Sorry, you're right `function-available()` works once you get it right. I had to use `xsltArgList.AddExtensionObject("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/xslt/xImage", xslImageExtension);` to get it to work (note the full URI). I found some good info (but no sample unfortunately) here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950776.aspx